# LibreOffice Base under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice v.3.5.7.2 under Ubuntu 12.04.  I would like to use Base, but it is greyed out.  Is there a way that I can download and install  a version of Base for my LibreOffice, or do I have to upgreade to a new version?

Comment: How did you install the rest of libreoffice? what does `apt-cache policy libreoffice-base` say?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have LibreOffice Base installed, you can obtain it by installing the [libreoffice-base](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libreoffice-base) [image: Install libreoffice-base] package. This package [is available for Ubuntu 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libreoffice-base), as well as other releases.

You can install it in the Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic Package Manager. Or you can install it from the command line (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) by running:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base
```

<sub>If you are able to install it, or find it is already installed, but you are still unable to run it, please update your question with details.</sub>

Comment: My response to the query "apt -cache policy libreoffice-base" is as follows:

Comment: ~$ apt-cache policy libreoffice-base
libreoffice-base:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.5.7-0ubuntu8
  Version table:
     1:3.5.7-0ubuntu8 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main i386 Packages
     1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages